# Access content of MainWindow from Page

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

I build a WPF application with MS Ribbon Menu.
On the Main Ribbon Window I defined a frame which displays different Pages.
Everything is working fine so far.
When I try to get or set any value in the embeeded page I do use the following command:

Example, moving the cursor in a listview when I click on a RibbonButton in the MainWindow.

```
((Page_Rules)MainFrame.Content).lvwTemplates.Items.MoveCurrentToLast();
```

Now I try to do something vice versa, to access something in MainWindow from a page class:

```
((MainWindow)Content).RibbonWindow.Group_References.IsEnabled = false;
```

However, this isn't working. I'm getting the following exception

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' to type
>   'MyApplication.MainWindow'

I'm wondering how I can access any control in the MainWindow from any of my embedded Pages

Answer (score 0):

You might use the VisualTreeHelper.GetParent to get the Visual Parent of your Page which is of MainWindow Type.
But note that with proper Binding, you shouldn't have to access controls directly. For your cursor example, you could have a ListViewIndex integer property, this property should raise PropertyChanged on change of course, and when you click on the RibbonButton, you just have to update ListViewIndex. (In this case you might want to have also a readonly property giving the number of items in the list). In your page which contains the listView, have the SelectedIndex bound to ListViewIndex and you don't have to access controls with code.